# Is there a way to play a ROSBAG on repeat?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get rosbag to play a bag file on loop?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257643/is-there-a-way-to-play-a-rosbag-on-repeat?/) by [ckirksey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29364/ckirksey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2017-03-22

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [giomig](https://answers.ros.org/users/77683/giomig/) on 2021-11-24**:
Is there a way to rosbag play a bagfile for N times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbag play -l bag_name.bag

---

Originally posted by [ckirksey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29364/ckirksey/) with karma: 203 on 2017-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ckirksey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29364/ckirksey/) on 2017-03-22**:
Couldn't find this answer when searching initially so I wanted to make it more visible.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-22**:
This seems pretty well documented over at [wiki/rosbag/Commandline - play](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#play)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-23**:
Also note btw that it's `-l` (single dash), not `--l`.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-24**:
Looks like you mixed up the shorthand and longhand. As gvdhoorn says, it's `rosbag play -l bag_name.bag` OR `rosbag play --loop bag_name.bag`

**Comment by [ckirksey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29364/ckirksey/) on 2017-03-24**:
Corrected. Thanks guys!